# Oracle Reports 11g - Oracle WebLogic - Reports Font

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, weblogic, oraclereports

I'm facing a issue when rendering a report. I've three environments:

- Local: Windows 10 x64
- Development: Linux RedHat 6.5
- Preprod: Linux RedHat 6.5

At firts the report had been design in the local environment with a font named 'Courier New', and when it's deployed in Local through the URL:

```
reports/rwservlet?server=<<SERVER>>&report=<<REPORT>>rep&destype=CACHE&desformat=PDF&paramform=no&<<REPORT_PARAMS>>
```

It generates all the information OK, but when it was copied and compiled in Development, it generated with weird characters, e.g:

'SUPERIORES' = 'ΣΥΠΕΡΙΟΡΕΣ'

'PROCESO' = 'ΠΡΟΧΕΣΟ'

'CONTRATO' = 'ΧΟΝΤΡΑΤΟΣ'

But, only a few text labels and fields where rendered with this glyphs, and other text rendered OK. I thought that maybe if I change the font from 'Courier New' to 'Consolas' (it's necesary to have a monospaced font) would resolve the problem. Indeed it was when deploying to Development environment.

The issue presents when deploying in Preprod environment, because although I've compiled the report from Development with the 'Consolas' font, all the text fields and labels with no exception are rendered with this glyphs, no matter if it is in upper or lower case, e.g:

'Alta de Contratos' = 'Αλτα δε Χοντρατοσ'

I've limited access to the configuration of both Development and Preprod Servers due control and permissions, but their settings was made by someone and they didn't replicated it correctly.

What I've tried so far is:

1. I made sure that the compiled resource (.rep file) is the same in both servers
2. Try to verify the files and configurations as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E72987_01/formsandreports/use-reports/pbr_font002.htm#i1005940), looks like no change since installation.
3. Verify the fonts in the `$ORACLE_INSTANCE/reports/fonts` in both servers, there is all the variations of the font 'Consolas' (Bold, Bold Italic, Italic, and Regular), as well as the 'Courier New'.
4. Check the `bash_profile` in both linux, no difference exists. Maybe this variable tell something `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P15`
5. I've realized that there is a folder in the `$REPORTS_PATH` of the Development env. that contains all the fonts, like the `$ORACLE_INSTANCE/reports/fonts` path and it is not in the preprod environment, so I replicated this folder to `$REPORTS_PATH` of preprod, but I know for sure there must be a setting like env. variable to tell weblogic that must read fonts from that directory, but I don't know where to set it.

I don't know what I'm missing, maybe those who have faced this problem could enlightme. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably totally unrelated, but trying to force a Linux environment to use an encoding other than UTF-8, when Linux has fully migrated to unicode more than a decade ago, is bound to fail somewhere. You're not using a legacy system like AIX, Solaris or Windows.